# Elasticsearch All shards failed for phase: [query]

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I have an elastsicsearch instance on AWS (I have a similar one that is working just fine.

I have a lambda function that ships logs to elasticsearch. It stopped working after a while and now I can't see any new logs. I looked into logs and found this :

```
org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [tqStC42][10.0.1.90:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: size must be positive, got 0
at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.BucketUtils.suggestShardSideQueueSize(BucketUtils.java:40) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.terms.TermsAggregatorFactory.doCreateInternal(TermsAggregatorFactory.java:100) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.support.ValuesSourceAggregatorFactory.createInternal(ValuesSourceAggregatorFactory.java:55) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AggregatorFactory.create(AggregatorFactory.java:225) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AggregatorFactories.createTopLevelAggregators(AggregatorFactories.java:102) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AggregationPhase.preProcess(AggregationPhase.java:61) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
at org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhase.execute(QueryPhase.java:104) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
at org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesService.lambda$loadIntoContext$18(IndicesService.java:1159) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
at org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesService.lambda$cacheShardLevelResult$20(IndicesService.java:1229) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
at org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesRequestCache$Loader.load(IndicesRequestCache.java:150) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
at org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesRequestCache$Loader.load(IndicesRequestCache.java:133) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
at org.elasticsearch.common.cache.Cache.computeIfAbsent(Cache.java:398) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
at org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesRequestCache.getOrCompute(IndicesRequestCache.java:116) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
at org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesService.cacheShardLevelResult(IndicesService.java:1235) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
at org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesService.loadIntoContext(IndicesService.java:1158) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.loadOrExecuteQueryPhase(SearchService.java:257) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:273) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
at org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchTransportService$6.messageReceived(SearchTransportService.java:300) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
at org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchTransportService$6.messageReceived(SearchTransportService.java:297) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:69) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$6.doRun(TransportService.java:577) [elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:527) [elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) [elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_111]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_111]
```

I did a curl on cluster health (yellow because one node)

```
{
   "cluster_name":"Pixel",
   "status":"yellow",
   "timed_out":false,
   "number_of_nodes":1,
   "number_of_data_nodes":1,
   "active_primary_shards":11,
   "active_shards":11,
   "relocating_shards":0,
   "initializing_shards":0,
   "unassigned_shards":11,
   "delayed_unassigned_shards":0,
   "number_of_pending_tasks":0,
   "number_of_in_flight_fetch":0,
   "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis":0,
   "active_shards_percent_as_number":50.0
}
```

A bit more information on the instance: 
it's on m4.4xlarge with 100 GB of EBS. It also uses 32 GB mem. So far has 600k records in one index.

What else should I look for?

I also cat the shards

```
pixel 1 p STARTED 130527 74.7mb 10.0.1.90 tqStC42
pixel 1 r UNASSIGNED 
pixel 3 p STARTED 129687 74.4mb 10.0.1.90 tqStC42
pixel 3 r UNASSIGNED 
pixel 2 p STARTED 130561 74mb 10.0.1.90 tqStC42
pixel 2 r UNASSIGNED 
pixel 4 p STARTED 129870 74.6mb 10.0.1.90 tqStC42
pixel 4 r UNASSIGNED 
pixel 0 p STARTED 129981 74.4mb 10.0.1.90 tqStC42
pixel 0 r UNASSIGNED
```

Comment: so to make your cluster go green, which I don't think is your problem here, you can do something like: `curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/*/_settings' -d '{"index" : {"number_of_replicas" : 0}}'` You of course need to change the domain. Or you could spin up a second ES node.

Comment: As far as the problem, I would look here: `org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [tqStC42][10.0.1.90:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: size must be positive, got 0`

Comment: @JamesR: What size is it referring to?

Comment: @tyrell_c Can you show us your search query ?

Comment: @tyrell_c I'd need to see the search query and probably the mapping as well. can you update your question?

Answer (score 3):

The error you're getting is because you have an aggregation query, probably a `terms`, `significant_terms` or `geohash_grid` one, in which you have specified `"size": 0` in order to get all the possible terms.

This was possible in ES 2.x and earlier releases, but [not anymore since ES 5.x](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/18838) because that can greatly harm performance. Now if you want to get all the terms of a given field, you have to explicitly set a high number like `"size": 1000` or whatever makes sense to you, it just needs to be a number bigger than the cardinality of your field.